# Entering rails console with AWS login from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-cli

I am in my app directory on terminal. I can enter rails console by using the following command

```
docker-compose run <app_name> rails c
```

However I am not able to access the console of the production environment.
I tried the following command:

```
docker-compose run app rails c production AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=****.... AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****.... AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=****...
```

The command above is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/base.rb:525:in `handle_argument_error': ERROR: "rails_console console" was called with arguments ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=****....", "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=****....] (Thor::InvocationError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  `rails c -e production` which is the correct one for the rails 5 and 6